# Update createStackNavigator with multiple routeConfigs to react-navigation 5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, stack-navigator

In my code i had a createStackNavigator that accepted routeConfigs as a set of objects on load. It used to vary in length and was handled by the function well. On upgrading to react navigation 5, i tried using Object.entries to traverse through the set of objects and Map it to Navigator and Screen. But is shows error that the returned component in Screen are not screens.
Any idea to traverse through?

` const components = {
{
name: "Home",
element: HomeScreen
},
{
name: "Details",
element: DetailsScreen
},
{
name: "User",
element: UserScreen
},
{
name: "Display",
element: DisplayScreen
}
};

Object.entries(components).map(([name, component]) => {

```
        return (
          <Stack.Screen 
        name={name}
        component={component}
      />
        );
      })`
```

Comment: Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: @RafaelTavares Added a sample code, its basically a large object of objects that i need to traverse through. And create a navigator component

Comment: Your `components` is an invalid object... If it is an array (`components = [...]`), then the code should be `components.map(({ name, element }) => ...)`

Comment: @RafaelTavares So i should convert it to an array. And then use it?

Comment: Well, this alternative seems to make more sense to me